# Gif in UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, ios8

```
var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("long1", ofType: "gif")
var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)     
var webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: view.frame)
webViewBG.loadData(gif, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false
self.view.insertSubview(webViewBG, atIndex: 0)
```

This is my code for adding a webview with a Gif loaded in it. However, while the web view may fill the view.frame, the .gif isn't filling the web view. Because of this, there are grey borders around the gif.

I've tried sizetoscale and various other tricks but they all didn't work!

**EDIT**

UIImage+animatedGIF works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the webview just because you need to show the gif? Because you can show a gif otherwise too. Use the UIImage+animatedGIF category

Comment: Hi! I integrated this lib in my swift 3 application but I don't know how to use it. Can you provide me please a swift example of use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have tried and what you haven't, but have you tried:

```
webViewBG.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.style.margin='0';document.body.style.padding = '0'")
```

After the webview has finished loading? You can do this by assigning yourself as the delegate when you make the webview:

```
webViewBG.delegate = self
```

And then adding `webViewDidFinishLoad` in your class, like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.body.style.margin='0';document.body.style.padding = '0'")
}
```

Comment: How should I be using this? I have my code placed in viewwillappear and just put this segment of code in viewdidappear and it seems to be not working